# How do I downgrade a package in devDependencies with yarn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I want to downgrade a package version from 3.0.1 to 3.0.0 ? I've tried yarn upgrade @ ...Also tried with --dev, but it didn't work. I wasn't able to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the desired verion number to the back of the package name like so:

```
yarn add packagename@3.0.0
```

Edit:

If wanting to add to devDependencies instead:

```
yarn add -D packagename@3.0.0
```

Comment: But that adds it to "dependencies" and leaves my package in devDependencies untouched. I need my node-fetch to be 3.0.0

Comment: to add to your dev dependencies instead do this: yarn add -D packagename@3.0.0